# How can we get result as Json array in ORDS?

Tags: json, oracle, oracle19c, json-arrayagg

Is there any possibility to get JSON array instead of JSON object as a result while calling REST API which is built by using Oracle Rest Data Services(ORDS)??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No because your required output is not valid JSON:

### Error: Parse error on line 3:
{"items" : [{ ["99","SSS","DD"}]

Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '['